# Apple's MailComposer Not Sending Email

Tags: mfmailcomposer

I ran Apple's MailComposer code without changing anything. I entered my email as the recipient but did not receive an email. Why is this not working? Did anybody else experience this?

Here is the link to the code:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865

Answer (score 0):

Did you run on Iphone Simulator? There the app just simulate the sending.